# How to delete object inside method?

Tags: java, oop

I am writing a database manager. There are method for adding an car into database and removing car.

```
public class DBManager {

public static void addCar(Car car) {
        ...
    }

public static void deleteCar(Car car) {
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM cars WHERE id = '" + car.getId() + "'");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Next I have class Car:

```
public class Car {
        private int id;
        private String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId(){
    return this.id;}
    }
```

I create and save car in method main. When I want delete car, car is deleted from database but I have object car in a programme and I can work with it. How I can delete carA inside method deleteCar?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Car carA = new Car("Opel");

       DBManager.addCar(carA);
       DBManager.deleteCar(carA);

    }
}
```

Comment: In your `main` method you can just do `carA = null;`.  I guess it's not clear to me what specifically you're looking to accomplish from within the method.  That method has no access to the `carA` variable.  It can access the `Car` instance and make any modifications you like on that, such as calling a method which might set all fields to empty values or something of that nature.  What specifically is the goal?

Comment: You can set carA object  to null after deleting the carA from dB.

Comment: You can't. `deleteCar` receives a reference to the Car object. After the call variable carA will still point to the Car object.